# Calling 4 methods one after the othe in android

Tags: android, methods, execution

I want to know how can I call 4 menthods one after the other in android. for example :

> start with method getSim()
>
> method getSim() when completed start method  getPhone()
>
> method  getPhone() when completed start method compare()
>
> method compare() when completed start method display()

```
 private void getSim()
    {
        System.out.println("In get Sim");
        Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn"); 
        
        Cursor cursorSim = context.getContentResolver().query(simUri,null,null,null,null);

        Log.i("PhoneContact", "total: "+cursorSim.getCount());
        if(cursorSim.getCount()>0)
        {
            while (cursorSim.moveToNext()) 
            {      
                ClsSimPhonename =cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("name"));
                ClsSimphoneNo = cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("number"));
                String xyz= ClsSimphoneNo.replaceAll("\\D","").replaceAll("&", "").replaceAll("\\(","").replaceAll("\\)","").replaceAll("\\s", "").replaceAll("-", "");
                Log.i("PhoneContact", "name: "+ClsSimPhonename+" phone: "+ClsSimphoneNo);
                   // getSimPhone.add(ClsSimPhonename+" sim");
                    getSimPhone.add(ClsSimPhonename);
                    mb.add(xyz);
            }
            cursorSim.close();
        }
    }`


`private void getPhone(){
        cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
      
        if(cursor.getCount()>0)
        {   
           while (cursor.moveToNext())
           {
               String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
               name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
               
               if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
               {
                   Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                          ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id}, null);
                   
                   while (pCur.moveToNext())
                   {
                       phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        mbnum =phone.replaceAll("\\(","").replaceAll("\\)","").replaceAll("\\s", "").replaceAll("-", "");
                       mb.add(mbnum);
                       
                      
                   }
                   pCur.close();
               }
            
               getSimPhone.add(name+" ph");
              
               
               
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }`

` private void compare()
{ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
            
            query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUserId);
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() 
            {
                public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, com.parse.ParseException e)
                {
                    if (e == null) 
                    {
                        for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) 
                        {
                            names.add(userList.get(i).getUsername().toString());
                            ph.add(userList.get(i).getString("mobile"));
                        }
                        
                        for(int z=0;z<mb.size();z++)
                        {
                            for (int i=0; i<ph.size(); i++)     
                            {
                                if(mb.get(z).equals(ph.get(i)))
                                {
                                 Toast.makeText(ShowContactsWithApp.this,"z mb"+mb.get(z)+ "\n i ph"+ph.get(i) + "\n z name" +getSimPhone.get(z)+"\n i name"+getSimPhone.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    values.add(getSimPhone.get(z));
                                 Toast.makeText(ShowContactsWithApp.this,"got a record",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(ShowContactsWithApp.this,"values count :"+values.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                       Toast.makeText(ShowContactsWithApp.this,"Error loading user list",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                 }
            });
            return values;
        }
}`

`display ()
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
                        lst.setAdapter(adapter);`
```

In first i get sim contacts , in second i get phone contacts ,in third i compare with parse stored contacts and in fourth i display the comparison.

Comment: provide the code you are trying to achive

Comment: This is the normal behavior of code (unless you are doing threading or async code). Just call them in order A(); B(); C(); D();

Comment: when i tr to post my code i get format error

Comment: can you please give a sample code to me

Comment: Put your code between the back tick characters ` like this `

Answer (score 2):

You just do this:

```
myMethod1();
myMethod2();
myMethod3();
myMethod4();
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this-

```
  A(){
   //here do your coding. at the end call next method
   //here  you can call your method B
   B();
   }

  B(){
   //here do your coding. at the end call next method
  //here  you can call your method C
  C();
  }
  C(){
   //here do your coding. at the end call next method
  //here  you can call your method D
  D();
  }

  D(){
   //here do your coding.
    }
```

Comment: I have tried it, but before all statement execution of A() before calling B() , B() is called. and so on.

Comment: @AnaghaMagar will you tell me which one is your method A, B, C, D ?

Comment: @AnaghaMagar   if possible then use try catch finally statement. i am not sure about it

Comment: getSim();, getPhone();, compare(); and display(); are the four methods ?

Comment: set i=1; inside your while loop, increment the value of i and check weather i==cursorSim.getCount(). if both are equal, then your while loop exit . so in that if loop, call next method.